# python3 pip installation of QMK failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, msys2

I am currently attempting to set up QMK on my laptop on [MSYS2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mingw-w64#MSYS2), following their documentation's instructions. When I enter the command `python3 -m pip install qmk`, I received an error that was initially about GCC not being installed. I addressed this issue and attempted the installation a second time, and this was the result:

```
Collecting qmk
  Using cached qmk-0.0.35-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs in c:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from qmk) (1.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from qmk) (0.4.3)
Collecting nose2
  Using cached nose2-0.9.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (137 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: hjson in c:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from qmk) (3.0.1)
Collecting argcomplete
  Using cached argcomplete-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (38 kB)
Collecting flake8
  Using cached flake8-3.8.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (72 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: yapf in c:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from qmk) (0.30.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.7 in c:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from nose2->qmk) (1.14.0)
Collecting coverage>=4.4.1
  Using cached coverage-5.2.1.tar.gz (694 kB)
Collecting mccabe<0.7.0,>=0.6.0
  Using cached mccabe-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.6 kB)
Collecting pyflakes<2.3.0,>=2.2.0
  Using cached pyflakes-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (66 kB)
Collecting pycodestyle<2.7.0,>=2.6.0a1
  Using cached pycodestyle-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (41 kB)
Installing collected packages: coverage, nose2, argcomplete, mccabe, pyflakes, pycodestyle, flake8, qmk
    Running setup.py install for coverage ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/python3.exe -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-qotf19e6/coverage/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-qotf19e6/coverage/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-record-zsz6mn90/install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:/msys64/mingw64/include/python3.8/coverage
         cwd: C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-qotf19e6/coverage/
    Complete output (99 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.mingw-3.8
    creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/annotate.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/backunittest.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/backward.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/bytecode.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/cmdline.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/collector.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/config.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/context.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/control.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/data.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/debug.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/disposition.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/env.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/execfile.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/files.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/html.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/inorout.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/jsonreport.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/misc.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/multiproc.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/numbits.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/optional.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/parser.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/phystokens.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/plugin.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/plugin_support.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/python.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/pytracer.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/report.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/results.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/sqldata.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/summary.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/templite.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/tomlconfig.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/version.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/xmlreport.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    copying coverage/__main__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage
    creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage/htmlfiles
    copying coverage/htmlfiles/coverage_html.js -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage/htmlfiles
    copying coverage/htmlfiles/index.html -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage/htmlfiles
    copying coverage/htmlfiles/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage/htmlfiles
    copying coverage/htmlfiles/jquery.hotkeys.js -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage/htmlfiles
    copying coverage/htmlfiles/jquery.isonscreen.js -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage/htmlfiles
    copying coverage/htmlfiles/jquery.min.js -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage/htmlfiles
    copying coverage/htmlfiles/jquery.tablesorter.min.js -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage/htmlfiles
    copying coverage/htmlfiles/keybd_closed.png -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage/htmlfiles
    copying coverage/htmlfiles/keybd_open.png -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage/htmlfiles
    copying coverage/htmlfiles/pyfile.html -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage/htmlfiles
    copying coverage/htmlfiles/style.css -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage/htmlfiles
    copying coverage/htmlfiles/style.scss -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage/htmlfiles
    creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage/fullcoverage
    copying coverage/fullcoverage/encodings.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/coverage/fullcoverage
    running build_ext
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-qotf19e6/coverage/setup.py", line 217, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-qotf19e6/coverage/setup.py", line 207, in main
        setup(**setup_args)
      File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 161, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/install.py", line 546, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-qotf19e6/coverage/setup.py", line 152, in run
        build_ext.run(self)
      File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 307, in run
        self.compiler = new_compiler(compiler=self.compiler,
      File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 1034, in new_compiler
        return klass(None, dry_run, force)
      File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/distutils/cygwinccompiler.py", line 310, in __init__
        CygwinCCompiler.__init__ (self, verbose, dry_run, force)
      File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/distutils/cygwinccompiler.py", line 127, in __init__
        if self.ld_version >= "2.10.90":
    TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/python3.exe -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-qotf19e6/coverage/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-qotf19e6/coverage/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-record-zsz6mn90/install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:/msys64/mingw64/include/python3.8/coverage Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have seen a few examples of similar errors happening for unrelated libraries and the advice given in those contexts does not seem to apply here. How can I correct for this error so that I can install QMK? I have reasons for ***not wanting to clone QMK*** from GitHub. Please do not suggest this.

Comment: I know this is going to sound obvious, but have you tried rebooting or reinstalling pip, or installing it into a venv to make sure dependencies don't clash. What os is this?

Comment: Do you have cygwin installed?

Comment: Information about ***versions*** for all the things ought to be [included](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63311460/edit): QMK, MSYS2, GCC, Python 3, pip, etc. But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).